# KeyError: "Unable to open object (object 'xxxxxx' doesn't exist)"

Tags: python, h5py

In part of my code, I create a dataset

```
with h5py.File('xxxxxx.h5', 'w') as f:
    f.create_dataset('xxxx', data=xxxxxx).
```

The code generates the .h5 file and stores it in the specified location, but once I want to open the file, it give me the following error:
[image: 1]

Any idea how to fix the problem? I appreciate it.

Comment: the error message is clear, are you sure the file name/ is correct when you read the file? extension usually used is `hdf5`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, please ensure you've included a complete, testable [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @eshirvana I tried .hdf5 and got the following error: OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = 'xxxxxxx.hdf5', errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', flags = 15, o_flags = 502)

Comment: @CrazyChucky Oh sorry, it was my first question and did not know. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error occurs when opening the file, you have an error in the file and/or path names.

To see how h5py ***should*** behave, run this code and inspect the resulting HDF5 file. First it creates a simple file and adds a single (3x3) dataset named 'xxxx' using the `data=` keyword. Then it re-opens the file and prints the dataset `.shape` and `.dtype` attributes, followed by the dataset values. Run this example in the same folder as your code and verify where the file is created. (Note: I used different file object names for demonstration purposes only.)

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('xxxxxx.h5', 'w') as fw:
    # create 3 datasets named: xxxx, yyyy, and zzzz
    vals1 = [[1., 2., 3.], [11., 12., 13.], [21., 22., 23.]] 
    fw.create_dataset('xxxx', data=vals1)
    vals2 = [[101., 102., 103.], [111., 112., 113.], [121., 122., 123.]]
    fw.create_dataset('yyyy', data=vals2)
    vals3 = [[1001., 1002., 1003.], [1011., 1012., 1013.], [1021., 1022., 1023.]]
    fw.create_dataset('zzzz', data=vals3)

    
with h5py.File('xxxxxx.h5', 'r') as fr:
    # print dataset shape and values
    print(fr['xxxx'].shape, fr['xxxx'].dtype)
    print(fr['xxxx'][()]
    print(fr['yyyy'][()])
    print(fr['zzzz'][()])

    # Alternate method to get dataset names from keys and print    
    for dset in fr.keys():
        print(dset,":",fr[dset].shape, fr[dset].dtype)
        print(fr[dset][()])
```

Comment: Thanks @kcw78 for your reply. I tried it and it worked, however, it is a little confusing for me: we are creating a .h5 file named "xxxxxx.h5" and add 'xxxx' to it. Does it mean that 'xxxx' is part of xxxxxx.h5? In other words, xxxxxx.h5 has different parts and 'xxxx' is one of them? thanks

Comment: Correct. HDF5 uses a Hierarchical Data Format of Groups and Datasets that mimics folders and files. xxxx is a dataset in file xxxxxx.h5. You can add another dataset to the file with a different name (say yyyy).

Comment: I modified the example to show how to create and read multiple datasets in the root group. If you have a lot of datasets, eventually you will want to use groups to organize them (like folders on a file system).

Comment: Thanks so much @kcw78, I appreciate it.